# Anonymous functions usage

Tags: php

Just wondering what the preferred method of using anonymous functions is.

First I had some code like this:

```
function page_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'author' => 'Author',
        'template' => 'Template',
        'date' => 'Date'
    );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-page_columns', 'page_columns');
```

But I know WordPress discourages using variables for things that will only be used once so I switched it to

```
function page_columns( $columns ) {
    return array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'author' => 'Author',
        'template' => 'Template',
        'date' => 'Date'
    );
}
add_filter('manage_edit-page_columns', 'page_columns');
```

But now I'm thinking why even use a function at all?

```
add_filter('manage_edit-page_columns', function(){
    return array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'author' => 'Author',
        'template' => 'Template',
        'date' => 'Date'
    );
});
```

What is the preferred method? Any reason why? Perhaps update the [WordPress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the second option.  Adding anonymous functions as filters and actions is ***highly discouraged!!!***

If you add an anonymous function in this fashion, it's impossible to remove later on down the road by other plugins and code.  So please, *please*, ***please*** don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

As EAMann said usage of anonymous functions prevents further removing of a function you strapping in.

However I would not discourage people from using it but make them aware of what they are doing.

Using an anonymous function is definitely a way to go in case when you need to make an irreversible changes.